# Adding Timestamp to each document added in ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

How can I create an Index and Mapping with the timestamp field so each added document will include a timestamp by default.

I am using NEST (C#) but I just cant figure out how to do it.

I am also using Kibana but it seems not to work properly because I am missing the timestamp field.

Also, after I am adding this field, is there any way I can 'confirm' the field is added? can I query this field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you index a document a [_timestamp](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) field can be automatically generated for each document.

To enable the timestamp, add the following to your mapping:

```
{
    "my_mapping" : {
        "_timestamp" : { "enabled" : true, "store" : true }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add it AFTER the map already exists?

Can I do it on an existing map?

Comment: You can enable the timestamp either when you first create the mapping or as an update to the mapping.  However you can only enable storage when creating the mapping - you can't add storage to an existing map.