# Add Timestamp to each document added in ElasticSearch - Nest 2.0

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

How can I make sure each document indexed in elasticsearch gets timestamped?

```
        node = new Uri("http://localhost:9201);
        settings =
            new ConnectionSettings(node).DefaultIndex("mytestindex");
        elasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

// Then I do
elasticClient.Index(connections, idx => idx.Id("1")
```

1. Using NEST and C# how can I make sure each document I index gets timestamp?
2. How can I query for all documents of type `<MyDoc>` with older than an hour ago?

I found this: [Adding Timestamp to each document added in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533368/adding-timestamp-to-each-document-added-in-elasticsearch)
however it doesn't show me how to do this with NEST

I've tried this, however looking at the result timestamp is null and it returns all documents in index:

```
        var test =
            elasticClient.Search<MyDoc>(
                s => s.Query(q => q.DateRange(x => x.LessThan(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable _timestamp but [_timestamp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) is deprecated. Don't use it anymore, just define a date properties in your data object and set it explicitly

```
await client.MapAsync<Blog>(m => m.TimestampField(t => t.Enabled(true)));
```